# Service static htm when app service is restarting

Tags: azure, .net-4.8

We have a lot of traffic to our website, and when we deploy an update to our app the app service will restart. This takes around 4-5 minutes to restart and this "App service unavailable" message is shown to every user visiting the page.

Using `app_offline.htm` in the `wwwroot` does not work.

Is there any way to serve a static html file when restarting your app service? Or when it is offline?

Comment: I would like to suggest a different approach: by using deployment slots you will be able to deploy the latest version to one slot (typically staging) and then hot swap to your live slot so your users will have a seamless experience.  Most production application plans will support deployment slots and are then included in the plan. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one default html file with the content which you want to show.

In *`web.config`* file , in `<system.webServer>` tag add the below snippet

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="index.html"/>
      </files>
  </defaultDocument>
<system.webServer>
```

Publish your web Application and check once.

- To edit the existing web.config , Go to kudu console in Azure Portal and edit.

***OR***

We can set ***Default Documents*** option in Azure Portal.

- After deploying your application to Azure.
- Go to Azure Portal => Your Application => Configuration =>Default Documents

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For whatever reason there is no question about this on this site, nor any blog post or documentation I could find. Maybe I was using the wrong search terms. But this helped a lot.

Comment: @Roy Berris - Glad that it was helpful, Thank you :)